# How to call Objective-C++ (.mm) from Objective-C (.m)

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

Is there a say to do this without changing every .m file to .mm?

OK.  I am trying to implement the answer but having trouble.  Take a look at my Objective C++ .h and .mm below

**Objective-C++ - IDCaptureTemplateCommand.h:**

```
#include "Template.h"

@interface IDCaptureTemplateCommand : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) IDCaptureTemplateCommand *IDCaptureTemplateCommand;

@end
```

**Objective-C++ - IDCaptureTemplateCommand.mm:**

```
#include "IDCaptureTemplateCommand.h"

@implementation IDCaptureTemplateCommand

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.captureTemplateCommand = [[IDCaptureTemplateCommand alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

**Objective-C - IDCameraViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "IDCaptureTemplateCommand.h"

@interface IDCameraViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) IDCaptureTemplateCommand *captureCommand;  //ERROR - Unknown type name 'IDCaptureTemplateCommand'

@end
```

Comment: I added my attempt to make it work, but I wouldn't have been able to do that without bames53's instructions.  Will you please take this off hold?

Comment: You should get out of the habit of importing header files into other header files. Most of the time, you do not need to do that. You only need to import a header for a class or protocol if you need to 1) subclass that class, or 2) implement that protocol in the header. For all other uses, including using the type of the pointer to that class, you should instead forward-declare it, like `@class IDCaptureTemplateCommand;`

Comment: I don't see any C++ in your code. Are you sure this is related to C++? Maybe you have a import cycle and `IDCaptureTemplateCommand.h` somehow imports `IDCameraViewController.h`? Are you sure that changing all the files to .mm makes it go away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so in the same way as you can use C++ from C or whatever. You need to be able to declare the interface using pure Objective-C and then the implementation can be written using Objective-C++.

If your header file uses C++, e.g. your class has an `std::string` instance variable, then to make the functionality accessible from Objective-C you have to write a wrapper or otherwise hide the C++ at the interface, so that your Objective-C files don't need to see any of the C++ declarations.

Comment: OK.  I've added my Objective-C++ header and implementation code.  Then added my Objective-C header file, which is where I am trying to use the Objective-C++ class.  What am I doing wrong to reference the Objective-C++ code from Objective-C?

Thank you.

Comment: I managed to get my Objective-C talking to my Objective-C++.  I couldn't have done it without this answer by bames53.  Whoever put this question on Hold missed the mark, because it was the advise I received by bames53 that broke the brick wall.  Thank you for your help, bames53.  :-)

Comment: I have added information and also included that I couldn't have figured this out without your help.  Can you see if Sebastian, Chris, Pragnesh Chauhan, tjameson, or Sumit Bijvani can take this question off hold?  Thank you.  Lucy

Comment: @Lucy There's no way to send users messages directly. I'm not sure if users get notified when you use the @ syntax with their name in a comment thread they haven't posted in. You can give it a try though.